# Apache / Django - CSS Not loading on Alias

Tags: python, css, django, apache

My CSS / JS is not loading when using an alias in the httpd.conf

The site loads with all static files when using the localhost

```
WSGIScriptAlias / "d:\www\python\skillshare\src\mvp_landing\wsgi.py"
```

result;

```
http://localhost/
```

The site loads but with no css and js when adding the alias

```
WSGIScriptAlias /picon "d:\www\python\skillshare\src\mvp_landing\wsgi.py"
```

result;

```
http://localhost/picon/
```

My Current Dir structure below;

```
D:\www\python\skillshare\src\mvp_landing\wsgi.py
D:\www\python\skillshare\src\manage.py

D:\www\python\skillshare\static\static\
D:\www\python\skillshare\static\media\
D:\www\python\skillshare\static\templates\
```

Below my current httpd.conf (apache2.2);

```
WSGIScriptAlias /picon "d:\www\python\skillshare\src\mvp_landing\wsgi.py"

<Directory "d:/www/python/skillshare/src/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

My Settings.py below

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

    # Template location
    TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "templates"),
    )

    if DEBUG:
        MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
        STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static")
        MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "media")
        STATICFILES_DIRS = (
            os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static"),
        )
```

My urls.py below

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^/$', 'signups.views.home', name='home'),

    url(r'^thank-you/$', 'signups.views.thankyou', name='thankyou'),
    url(r'^about-us/$', 'signups.views.aboutus', name='aboutus'),

    url(r'^customers/$', 'formlist.views.customers', name='customers'),
    url(r'^addcustomer/$', 'formlist.views.addcustomer', name='addcustomer'),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                          document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Currently i am at a loss to which setting to adjust to get the static files working with the alias in place, any suggestion would be very much appreciated. Please let me know if additional setup information is required to answer the question.

Setup:

```
Windows server 2012 64bit
WAMP
Apache 2.2
Python 2.7
Django 1.6
Bootstrap (latest)
```

regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you add the Alias for static in your httpd.conf ? Something like:

```
Alias /static/ D:\www\python\skillshare\static\static

<Directory D:\www\python\skillshare\static\static>
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

Great, I had to remove the / to get it to work, but it worked!

```
Alias /static D:\www\python\skillshare\static\static

<Directory D:\www\python\skillshare\static\static>
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: I edited my answer to remove the _/_. I'm happy to hear that you found the solution!